# Writing code on System 6?

Tags: terminal, classic-mac-os

I have a Macintosh SE FD HD running Apple System 6. Is there a Terminal application? What programming language(s) can I run on System 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no terminal application for System 6, at least not out of the box.  There is [Macintosh Programmers Workshop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_Programmer%27s_Workshop) and a couple of other oddities around, as well as things like telnet clients for connecting to other computers.

While I don't know all possible programming languages, MPW will give you a command line, C, C++, and Pascal.  Other languages I've seen were Chipmunk BASIC, Perl, and other development environments that were common were Think C and Metrowerks CodeWarrior.  Here is a random [webpage](http://www.euronet.nl/users/mvdk/developtoday.html) about it.

Comment: @Moshe, I'd poke around the entire site, http://www.euronet.nl/users/mvdk/develop.html.

It looks to be fairly updated and you'll probably find a lot of valuable information over there.

Comment: Thanks @SoFly I should have linked there rather than to the one I did.

Comment: Here is the last snapshot of the aforementioned link before the site went down: https://web.archive.org/web/20170221202216/http://www.euronet.nl/users/mvdk/develop.html